# How to print my name 100 times without any looping using C#?

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, printing, console.writeline

How I can print my name 100 times without using loops in C#? Any clues?
I have already tried to print number 1 to 100 without using loops but how I can do it with string(my name)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like you know about recursion. Can you show your attempt?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("name");Console.WriteLine("name");Console.WriteLine("name");Console.WriteLine("name");Console.WriteLine("name");Console.WriteLine("name");` etc... ;)

Comment: well recursion with a counter is in the end just a complicated for loop, so this wont help

Comment: Joke aside, it sounds like you already have it working with numbers... just swap your current `Console.WriteLine(number);` for `Console.WriteLine("name");`. Or is there something specific you're struggling with?

Comment: You could do this a bunch of different ways...recursion although recursion is just a loop in my opinion, using an if statement with a count calling functions that call another function with counts which way would you like to see...show us what your doing with the numbers and we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Console.WriteLine(
   String.Join(
      ", ", 
      Array.ConvertAll<int, string>(
         Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray(), 
         i => i.ToString()
      )
   )
);

Answer (score 9):

I guess it comes down to what your definition of loop is.

**Recursion**

```
public static void Recurse(int count)
{
   if(count == 0) return;
   Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
   Recurse(count - 1);
}
```

---

**Fancy pants *linq***

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("bobo"));
```

or supplied by [MKR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8176478/mkr)

```
Console.Write(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Robo\n", 100))
```

<sub>***Note*** : this still loops underneath, via an iterator method</sub>

---

**I'm a kid from the 80's [goto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto)**

```
public static void Goto(int count)
{     
   startLoop:
   if (count-- <= 0)return;
   Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
   goto startLoop;
}
```

---

**2 finger *Copy/Paste* loop**

```
Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
Console.WriteLine("Bobo");
...
```

Comment: `2 finger Copy/Paste loop` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ that's great.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ the best loop of all

Comment: Or `Console.Write(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Robo\n", 100)));`

Comment: Funny. But it is still loops all the way down. Except the last one :-)

Comment: @TaW yeah they are indeed

Comment: Thanks for all!! :-)